# I accidentally put an extra close curly bracket

Tags: html, css

I am stuck with an extra close curry bracket in CSS that I accidentally put prior writing other lines. If I leave it there, it acually does no harm to the result. However, when I remove it, the position of other elements are repositioned.

*(( In lines of code, the extra close curly bracket is where the arrow pointing ))*

**Please click on the links below to see both results.**

**Question**:      Is there any way to remove it without repositioning other elements?

[Without the Close Curly Bracket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqALl.png)

[With the Close Curly Bracket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLGys.png)

```
body{
 font: 15px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 p(color#282f38);
 background-color: #F5F2ED;
 font:696863;
}

/*Global*/
 .container{
 width:80%;
 margin:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
}

ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

/* Header */
 #fixed{
 position: fixed;
}

header{
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 background:#282f38;
 color:#F5F2ED;
 padding-top: 10px;
 min-height:50px;
 border-bottom:#F5F2ED 3px solid;
}

header a{
 color:#F5F2ED;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size: 18px;
}

header li{
 float:left;
 display: inline;
 padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #resume{
 float: left;
}

header #resume h1{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

header nav{
 position: relative;
 left: 30%;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
header .highlight, header .current a{
 color:#696863 ;
 font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover{
 color:#696863;
 font-weight: bold;
}

/* Showcase */
 #showcase {
 min-height: 350px;
 background: url('../Resources/Photographer.png') no-repeat 0 -120px;
 align-items: center;
 color: #ffffff;
 overflow: auto;
}

#showcase h1{
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 100px;
 font-size: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#showcase p{
 text-align:justify;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-size: 14;
 text-indent: inherit;
}

/* Social Medias*/

#socialmedias{
 position:fixed;
 padding-top: : 5px;
 right: 20px;
 top: 130px;
 display: block;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 font: inherit;
 list-style-type: none;
}

}    <<-----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* Message Me Box */
#box{
 width: 30%;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 1px;
}
/* Box Border */
 .fieldset{
 display: inline-block;
 border: 3px solid;
 float: right;
}
/* Message Me Title */
 #legend{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#282f38;
}
/* Name Input */
 #form-name{
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Email Input */
 #form-email{
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Message Input */
 #form-message{
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Contact */
 .button_contact{
 position: relative;
 height: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 background:#696863;
 color: #F5F2ED;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can run your code through a linting tool

Comment: Hi @PhumchaiPipatanamongkol, as a general tip, if selecting ID's on a page (e.g. `header #resume {`), you should not need to be any more specific than just using the ID (i.e `#resume {`). Only be as specific as you need to be. Additionally, your use of the `header` selector is very dangerous, as `header` is a general element, meaning your page could have multiple `header` tags. You presumably only want your styles to apply to the page header rather than all `header` tags that may appear on your page, so I recommend using a class or ID on the header.

Comment: Thank you so much Anurag Daolagajao and Edmund Reed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra curly bracket is being treated as part of the selector for the next rule. i.e. the rule is

```
} #box {
 width: 30%;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 1px;
}
```

So `} #box` matches nothing. When you remove the `}`, the selector is `#box` and matches the element with id "box".

If you don't want the effect you get when removing the extra `}`, remove the entire rule.

Comment: My sincere gratitude for your time and help!!

Answer (score 2):

Not just one error,

Check the comments I added in your code.

Best way to avoid these errors are using an IDE.
There are so many open source tools available. For example NetBeans.

They can help you to identify your errors. 
Check this screenshot, they are easy to use also.

[image]

```
/* Social Medias*/

#socialmedias{
 position:fixed;
 padding-top: : 5px; // Error 1, 
 right: 20px;
 top: 130px;
 display: block;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 font: inherit;
 list-style-type: none;
}

}    // Error 2

body{
 font: 15px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 p(color#282f38);  // Error 3
 background-color: #F5F2ED;
 font:696863;
}
```

Comment: My gratitude for your clarification and time!!

Answer (score 2):

You have many errors in your css. I've validated your css on [W3C CSS Validator](http://www.css-validator.org/)

[image]

I've changed your CSS. See below:

```css
body {
 font: 15px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #F5F2ED;
}

p {
 color: #282f38;
}

/*Global*/
.container {
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* Header */
#fixed {
 position: fixed;
}

header {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 background: #282f38;
 color: #F5F2ED;
 padding-top: 10px;
 min-height: 50px;
 border-bottom: #F5F2ED 3px solid;
}

header a {
 color: #F5F2ED;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 18px;
}

header li {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #resume {
 float: left;
}

header #resume h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

header nav {
 position: relative;
 left: 30%;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a {
 color: #696863;
 font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
 color: #696863;
 font-weight: bold;
}

/* Showcase */
#showcase {
 min-height: 350px;
 background: url('../Resources/Photographer.png') no-repeat 0 -120px;
 align-items: center;
 color: #ffffff;
 overflow: auto;
}

#showcase h1 {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 100px;
 font-size: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#showcase p {
 text-align: justify;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-indent: inherit;
}

/* Social Medias*/
#socialmedias {
 position: fixed;
 padding-top: 5px;
 right: 20px;
 top: 130px;
 display: block;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 font: inherit;
 list-style-type: none;
}

/* Message Me Box */
#box {
 width: 30%;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 1px;
}
/* Box Border */
.fieldset {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 3px solid;
 float: right;
}
/* Message Me Title */
#legend {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #282f38;
}
/* Name Input */
#form-name {
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Email Input */
#form-email {
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Message Input */
#form-message {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Contact */
.button_contact {
 position: relative;
 height: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #696863;
 color: #F5F2ED;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Header */
 ----------------->#fixed{<------------------
 position: fixed;
}
```

Try to change the id where the arrow is pointed, use class for that, because there are so many conflicts, if we use IDs directly. For more information please find the link below:

https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/disallow-ids-in-selectors

Comment: Thank you very much for help

Answer (score -1):

i think there is something to do with "#fixed" id name in the html and css.
try to change the name to something else. The property and your name might be colliding with each other. So change it...

Comment: Thank you for your time and help

Comment: @PatrickMlr you're right, but it does highlight an issue with SO's syntax highlighting.